# How can I search for a file in a website?

Tags: url

For example I want to list all of the pdf files under this address: example.com/folder/folder/?.pdf

How can I do that?
I already tried url fuzzer but it returned only 10 pdfs but there is more.

Comment: Do you have access via FTP or are you only able to access HTTP urls?

Comment: Only able to access HTTP urls

Comment: Then the only thing you can do is bruteforce filenames, which is a lengthy and inefficient process.

Comment: Can you give me a program that can brute force URLs?

Comment: I posted an aswer. Can you accept it so that this question will be flagged as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question posted [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39930/automated-url-discovering).

What you can use is [wfuzz](https://github.com/xmendez/wfuzz), an URL discovery tool.

The topic I posted above has an answer which explains more about what you are looking for:

> Discovery of URLs in the wild tends to be done in one of three ways
>
> 1. Search Engine Based. If your content gets indexed by a search engine, it's discoverable. this doesn't just include them hitting your
>      site directly, if other sites link to the content it may be findable
>      that way.
> 2. "known URLS". There's a lot of URLs that are known to be things like administrative interfaces or CGIs with known issues. Tools like
>      nikto maintain a database of them and can be used by attackers to
>      discover systems which have that software installed.
> 3. Brute-force. Tools like OWASP DirBuster combined with lists of common directory/file names can be used to discover content.
>
> In terms of an untargeted attack unless you have a common vulnerable
>   piece of software (e.g. phpmyadmin) hosted on a default URL, it's
>   unlikely you'll have a problem as the sheer number of sites on the
>   Internet make it unlikely that you'll face a human attacker focused on
>   finding content on your site.
>
> With a targeted attacker tools like nikto and dirbuster would be
>   usuable to try and find content on your site.
>
> If you have information that you don't want to be found I would
>   recommend adding authentication and SSL to it to prevent unauthorised
>   access to it.